# Issue with fs.unlink in Nest JS: Cannot read property 'unlink' of undefined

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest

I was encountering an issue while trying to delete a file using the fs module in Node.js. Here's the code snippet I initially used:

```
 import fs from 'fs';
 .
 .
 .

 @Delete(':fileName')
 async deleteFile(@Param('fileName') fileName: string) {
  await fs.unlink('../../uploads/${fileName}', (err) => {
   if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return err;
   }
  });
 }
```

However, this code was not working as expected, and I received the following error:

> Cannot read property 'unlink' of undefined.

After some investigation, I discovered the issue was with how I was importing the fs module. I resolved the problem by changing the import statement as follows:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Comment: What about it "doesn't work" Are you getting errors? Is the file not deleting? We need more information to be able to help.

Comment: btw fs.unlink doesn't return a Promise so the `await` there doesn't make sense. I advise you to use the promise API of `fs` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_unlink_path

Comment: The error I was getting was `Cannot read property 'unlink' of undefined`. The problem solved when I changed the import from `import fs from 'fs';` to `import * as fs from 'fs';`

Comment: Also, async is needed becouse I'm using `fs.unlink`. For sync function use `fs.unlinkSync`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error I was getting was `Cannot read property 'unlink' of undefined`. The problem solved when I changed the import from `import fs from 'fs';` to `import * as fs from 'fs';`

PD: Make sure you use the correct path (machine path) of the archive inside `fs.unlink(path, callback)`.

Comment: solved by this import! (Y)